# What will happen if clients change javascript code

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am comparing two Time/Date objects in JavaScript e.g. time1, time2 in **if** condition. When both times are equal a function is called and SERVER is update using Ajax.

My question is when page is loaded in client's browser and if user do inspect element or change the source code then will this function call occur that I mentioned upper?

Comment: So what will happen? It's their browser - they can do whatever they want.

Comment: What do you real want to achieve? This doesnt seem to be a save methode.

Comment: I am working on a bus ticket project. In which on ticket closing date bus should disappear from reservation list. so I am comparing current date with closing date.

Comment: I think i should use PHP functionality.

Answer (score 2):

It might occur. It depends on what the user does and how your code reacts to that. It is certainly possible for the user to trigger the HTTP request to the server.

You can't trust anything beyond the borders of your server.

If you need to *know* that a certain amount of time has passed (for example) then measure it on the server using data stored on the server and connected to a browser via a session.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using inspection user can change all your javascript codes. so the 'time variables' you defined can be changed.

Note that most of security is serverside, so recheck if you need any security checks & filters in serverside or not!

If you think you may have security problems with this, I seriously advise read some articles about javascript &  security.

Comment: And I seriously suggest you to not call it "ajax security", since there is nothing special in ajax requests, it's just an ordinary HTTP request.

Comment: for comparing two times are dates server side script should be use. I think its more secure.

Comment: @zerkms I mean all security conditions and tips that should observe during using Ajax.. ;)

Comment: @ShayanKM and that's the problem. Those should be applied irregardless if ajax is used or not.

Comment: @khurram you should use javascipt for comparing these 2 variables, but you should check what would happen if these changes by user in diffrent scenarios and if any trouble was found, do some filters in serverside to solve that.

Comment: @zerkms I agree with you bro.. my mistake is edited.

Comment: @ShayanKM nice suggestion I will try it. thanks all participators